# Squarespace drop up menu not functioning correctly (clickable part vanishing from view)

Tags: css, content-management-system, dropdown, squarespace

I am working on a custom Squarespace project for a client, and having trouble with a dropdown menu. Squarespace's default is to have the menu push down all other content blocks on the page. To prevent this, I had applied a z-index that helped it overlap over the rest of the page content on a different page, but it's not working on the default Squarespace blog page layout. So my alternative was to have the menu drop-up instead, but this is malfunctioning as the clickable part of the menu vanishes as soon as it is clicked. It also cuts off the upper part of the menu.

Please note the Squarespace CMS idiosyncrasies - as I can only go in and modify what's already there, the id and class names are not my choice. The dropdown menu is part of an "Archive block" that I am manipulating. The bottom property is positioning the menu where it needs to be on the page.

Page: https://www.youbelongsd.com/blog/

My code:

```
#collection-5b4791458a922da6575e66cf {
.archive-block-wrapper.archive-block-setting-layout-dropdown {
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1!important;
        bottom: -90%;
  }
}
```

In contrast, you can see the correctly functioning menu on a separate landing page I created for the blog to live on: https://www.youbelongsd.com/new-blog

(Because of the way Squarespace works, when individual post categories are clicked on, they direct you to the default blog page, the one that's causing problems with the dropdown/up menu. Otherwise I wouldn't even be messing with it.)

I've tried changing the z-index (no effect), adjusting display (no effect), and adjusting the bottom property which just moves the whole thing up and down. I added an overflow property, but that just created an awkward horizontal scroll bar. Any advice would be appreciated.